# Why cannot CDO Object for SMTP accept Mail.Sender.SMTPAddress object as .to property?

Tags: vbscript, smtp, outlook-redemption, cdo.message

I am reading senduser emails with Redemption library and trying to send the email through SMTP CDO.Object.

I have been receiving following **error**, as long as I get the email for **"EX"** senderEmailType through `Mail.Sender.SMTPAddress`: ***CDO.Message.1: The transport lost its connection to the server.***

Here is my code snippet (will lead to an error as long as **mailReceiver** argument is taken through `Mail.Sender.SMTPAddress` Redemption property - even converted to string it leads to the same error  - `cStr(Mail.Sender.SMTPAddress)`) Although when I change the mailReceiver Property to the same email as string - it does not generate any error like this (`maiLReceiver = "xx@like.com"`):

```
sub sendMailSMTP(mailSubject, mailSender, mailReceiver, CC, BCC, replyTo, HTMLBody, attachmentsPath_List, REMOTE_SMTP, SMTP, PORT_SMTP, SCHEMAS)
HTML_CID = ""
set CDOObject = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
with CDOObject
    .subject = mailSubject
    .from = mailSender
    .to = mailReceiver
    .CC = CC
    .BCC = BCC
    .replyTo = replyTo
    .HTMLBody = HTMLBody & HTML_CID
    .TextBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
    .AddAttachment LOGO_MAIL
    .Attachments(1).Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-disposition") ="attachment;filename="& replace(split(LOGO_MAIL, "\")(ubound(split(LOGO_MAIL, "\"))),".jpg","")
    .Attachments(1).Fields.Update
    for each attachmentPath in attachmentsPath_List
        .AddAttachment attachmentPath
    next
end with

with CDOObject.Configuration.Fields
    .Item(SCHEMAS & "sendusing") = REMOTE_SMTP
    .Item(SCHEMAS & "smtpserver") = SMTP
    .Item(SCHEMAS & "smtpserverport") = PORT_SMTP 
    .Item(SCHEMAS & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    .Update
end with 
CDOObject.Send
set CDOObject = Nothing
end sub
```

Could anyone point me to the right direction, what may be the reason for that?

Comment: Are you connecting to an Exchange server's SMTP endpoint that only allows routing to the local mailboxes?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko no.

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the SMTP address in your code?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko if I hardcode mail address of receiver in my code, it works yes.

Comment: Sounds like the `Mail.Sender.SMTPAddress` property doesn't contain a valid email address format. Try outputting the value of `Mail.Sender.SMTPAddress` first.

Comment: @user692942, I already did it and the email is correct. When I hardcode it, the code does not throw any error and connection is successful.

Comment: Does it work for any SMTP address or just for your SMTP address?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko It works for any SMTP email address when I hardcode it.

Comment: @NikOhler are you replacing the `mailReceiver` with the output value like for like, if you are then I'm lost as to how this wouldn't work. If however you are assuming the result based on what you've observed from `Mail.Sender.SMTPAddress` that wouldn't be a like for like test. We would need to understand what the `Mail` object is and how you are using it, is it a COM object is a custom class etc.? I'm guessing it has something to do with Redemption, is the `SMTPAddress` property a string datatype?

Comment: Interesting, [the documentation](https://dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressEntry.htm) sheds some light - "String, read-only. Returns the SMTP address of the given user. If the address type is "SMTP", the returned value is the same as that returned by the Address property. If the address type is "EX", Redemption tries to retrieve the PR_SMTP_ADDRESS property, if unsuccessful, it retrieves the default SMTP address from the PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES Extended MAPI property.". So it's not always a like for like email address, depends on the `Type`.

Comment: @user692942 - i replace it directly. Moreover if I assign this value to new variable, it will also work: 

SMailTo = Mail.Sender.SMTPAddress
MailTo = SMailTo 

With MailTo it will work as well.

Comment: @user692942 - I prove both and the result is for sure correct. 


`select case Mail.SenderEmailType 
case "EX"
SMail_MailSendTo = replace(cstr(Mail.Sender.SMTPAddress)," ","")
case "SMTP" 
SMail_MailSendTo = replace(cstr(Mail.SenderEmailAddress)," ","")
 end select`